# Replace dictionary value from another dictionary value

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries, `First_Dict` and `Second_Dict`:

```
First_Dict = {'Texas': 'Austin', 'California': 'San Diego', 'Florida': 'Miami', 
             'Arizona': 'Phoenix'}

Second_Dict = {'Family1': ['This family went to Arizona.'], 'Family2': ['This 
family went to Texas.'], 'Family3': ['This family went to California.']}
```

Goal: For every state mentioned in `Second_Dict`, I need to match that value to the key on `First_Dict`. If there's a match, replace the `Second_Dict`'s value with the value from the `First_Dict` key.

So the output would look like this:

```
Second_Dict = {'Family1': ['This family went to Phoenix.'], 'Family2': 
          ['This family went to Austin.'], 'Family3': ['This family went to 
            San Diego.']}
```

I'm stumped on this one. A guiding hand would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dict comprehension:

```
import re
print({k:[' '.join([First_Dict.get(re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]','',i),i) for i in v[0].split()])+'.'] for k,v in Second_Dict.items()})
```

Output:

```
{'Family1': ['This family went to Phoenix.'], 'Family2': ['This family went to Austin.'], 'Family3': ['This family went to San Diego.']}
```

**Update:**

```
Second_Dict = {k:[' '.join([First_Dict.get(re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]','',i),i) for i in v[0].split()])+'.'] for k,v in Second_Dict.items()}
```

And then now `Second_Dict` is the dictionary,

So:

```
print(Second_Dict)
```

Is:

```
{'Family1': ['This family went to Phoenix.'], 'Family2': ['This family went to Austin.'], 'Family3': ['This family went to San Diego.']}
```

Comment: @vmx1987 Voted for the question too, every question i answer, i upvote the question :-)

Comment: Sweet! I really need to learn more about list and dict comprehension. Just started doing python or scripting in general.

Comment: @vmx1987 Yeah, I think you're having a good start, i can give you a link to where i learned from: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/

Comment: How would you go about editing the code to where instead of just printing the result, it would actually change on the dictionary permanently afterwards?

Comment: @vmx1987 Done the edit, just got back to my computer and did it in a second to help you :-)